# Задача про паркет

Tags: алгоритм, комбинаторика, динамическое-программирование

Есть поле из клеток, размеры которого [n * m]. Необходимо покрыть это поле плитками размера [1 * 2] (их можно поворачивать) таким образом, чтоб все клетки поля были накрыты, и чтоб плитки не вылазили за границы поля. Задача состоит в том, чтоб найти количество таких покрытий.

Данную задачу я решил с помощью динамики по профилю. Профиль - состояние одного столбца поля. Подразумевается, что слева от данного профиля уже все клетки заполнены, а справа ещё нет. Переход из профиля в профиль существует, если можно корректно положить некоторое количество плиток (переходы хранятся в матрице dp).

Затем я считаю матрицу ответов:

```
if (dp[j][i]) ans[k][i] += ans[k - 1][j];
```

И после посчитанной матрицы ответов считаю ответ на задачу

`if (isFinishing(i)) res += ans[m - 1][i];`

Эта строчка означает, что если профиль может являться завершающим, то добавить это число в ответу.

Данное решение вполне себе работает. Но затем я нашел модификацию данной задачи. Модификация состоит в том, чтобы найти количество таких покрытий, в которых не будет сплошных линий из плиток [1 * 2].

Пример: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первая картинка - это пример того, какими должны быть покрытия, вторая - какими не должны.

У меня был вариант хранить в динамике ещё состояние для каждой строки, была ли она перекрыта хоть раз вертикальной плиткой, и добавлять к ответу только эти варианты. Возможно, это бы и работало, но я не особо понимаю, как это реализовать.

Подскажите, как реализовать, или предложите свои варианты решения.

Comment: Кнут занимается подобными задачами в "Искусстве программирования", т. 4А, раздел 7.1.4 (начиная со стр. 295 русского издания; еще см. задача 7.1.4.215. Правда, у него другие методы :)

Comment: Слева от профиля клетки заполнены, справа пустые, а в самом профиле какие-то заполнены, а какие-то пустые?

Comment: "в которых не будет сплошных линий из плиток" - по идее, левая картинка тоже не прокатывает, т.к. плитки расположенные вдоль своих широких сторон - тоже образуют линию.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно сделать динамически по рядам длины `n`. Для каждого промежуточного решения хранить состояние "дырок", куда можно подставить вертикальные плитки. Установим, что мы всегда движемся сверху вниз, значит дырки будут внизу. Динамический массив будет иметь вид:

```
[int ряды, bool[] дырки] = кол-во решений
```

Например, все возможные решения для 1 ряда длиной 4:

```
[1, [0, 0, 1, 1]] = 1 // [xx] . .
[1, [1, 0, 0, 1]] = 1 // . [xx] .
[1, [1, 1, 0, 0]] = 1 // . . [xx]
[1, [1, 1, 1, 1]] = 1 // . .  . .
```

0 - горизонтальная плитка, 1 - пустое место для будущей вертикальной плитки. Количество нулей идущих подряд всегда должно быть парным, все нули запрещены (что бы удовлетворить ваше условие).

Дальше мы пытаемся соединить решение для `x-1` рядов с решением для `1` ряда, что бы получить решение для `x` рядов:

```
for (prev in solutions[x-1])
for (single in solutions[1])
{
    if (дырки prev совместимы c дырками single)
    {
        holes = считаем как будут выглядеть дырки после совмещения 2 решений
        solutions[x][holes] += prev;
    }
}
```

Конечным решением будет значение `solutions[m, [0, 0, 0, 0, ... 0]]`, где все нули - это полностью заполненный последний ряд.

Возможно существует более элегантное решение.